# Not able to execute the bat files from WIX bundle

Tags: installation, wix, bundle

I was creating a wix installer for my product.
I need to run mainly 3 sections in the installer.

1. Install the postgres database as pre-requisites
2. Install my product(I have created a msi for my product using wix)
3. Execute the database scripts(batch file which in turns executes some sql files).

For these steps, I created a wix bundle, and executed the exe package for the postgres database.
Then I executed the msi package for my product. And finally I need to run the batch file. So I used the same bundle and added exe package as shown below

```
    < Chain >
        
        <ExePackage Id="PostgresInstaller" ......>
        </ExePackage>       
    
        
        <MsiPackage Id="MyProductPackage" ...... >          
        </MsiPackage>

        <ExePackage Id="DatabaseScipts"                     
                    DisplayName="DatabaseScipts"
                    Description="Configuration files for database"
                    SourceFile="Scripts\create.bat"                     
                    />          
    </Chain>
```

But the problem is, the create.bat file inturns calls some sql files from some other directory. I have added those files in bundle project. But it is not
coming with final bundle exe. Is there any other way to include the sql files in the bundle.
My aim is to execute the bat having sql files after the msi package installer.

Answer (score 0):

In product.wxs file, make sure you include all the files needed.

```
<!-- Step 1: Define the directory structure -->
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="My Application Name"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <!-- Step 2: Add files to your installer package -->
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
            <Component Id="create.bat" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
                <File Id="create.bat" Source="Scripts\create.bat" KeyPath="yes"/>
            </Component>
//Other required files in similar ways
        </DirectoryRef>
```

In product.wxs page (not bundle.wxs), add a custom action something like this:

```
<Fragment>
    <CustomAction 
      Id='RunDbScript' 
      Directory='INSTALLDIR'
      Execute='commit' 
      Impersonate='yes'      
      ExeCommand='&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C &quot;[INSTALLDIR]create.bat&quot;'
      Return='check'/>
  </Fragment>
```

And add install execute sequence:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="RunDbScript" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```